# Ubuntu Charles Proxy Mobile Devices IOS/Android

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-14.04, charles-proxy

Are there any more configurations needed to be set for Charles Proxy to work on Ubuntu with mobile devices to capture the traffic?  I have installed Charles Proxy on Ubuntu and launched it with sudo bash ./charles. It does launched it but there are warnings and errors  .

INFO    [com.xk72.charles.CharlesContext] - LOAD CONFIG: /root/.charles.config
INFO    [com.xk72.charles.gui.transaction.viewers.gen.ImageBodyViewer] - Error initialising WebP image reader: no webp-imageio in java.library.path
WARNING  [com.xk72.charles.gui.transaction.viewers.gen.ImageBodyViewer] - No WebP image reader initialised, WebP image viewing will not be available
INFO    [com.xk72.charles.gui.transaction.viewers.gen.ImageBodyViewer] - Error initialising WebP image reader: Could not initialize class com.luciad.imageio.webp.WebP

Moreover, when the mobile devices are set with manually proxy in the Http Proxy tab with the ip of Ubuntu (in the same network) and the port number. IF the same steps are done on a mac, Charles proxy will prompt me to accept the incoming connections. BUT it never happen to me on Ubuntu and there is not traffic going through the proxy.  any pointer? I am thinking. Do we need to open the proxy in Ubuntu ? Thank you

Now the devices are able to go through the proxy and connect to internet, However, while there are two instances for Charles proxy running, only one configuration file. How would that work, trying to two Charles proxy with different throttling setting on different ports within one os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps check the firewall configuration on the Ubuntu machine. Maybe it is blocking incoming requests to port 8888?